# Example of on.exit, add argument

Tags: r

Can someone provide me with a simple usage case where the on.exit() function's "add" argument is true?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a very simple example

```
myfun <- function(x){
    on.exit(print("first"))
    on.exit(print("second"), add = TRUE)
    return(x)
}

myfun(2)
#[1] "first"
#[1] "second"
#[1] 2
```

Also note what happens without the add=TRUE parameter

```
fun <- function(x){
    on.exit(print("first"))
    on.exit(print("second"))
    return(x)
}

fun(2)
#[1] "second"
#[1] 2
```

The second call to on.exit removes the first call if you don't add the "add=TRUE".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know R but reading [the definition of onexeit](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/on.exit.html), `add = true` makes sure that the first expression is evaluated in addition to any previously stored onexit experssions, while `add = false` overwrites the previous one.

So looking around I found this on [jhsph.edu](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/biostat776/readData.R):

**It appears to basically ensure that `tmp` is also closed as well as  `file` on exit**

```
readData2 <- function(file, ...) {
        file <- file(file, "r")
        on.exit(close(file))

        tmp <- tempfile()
        tmpcon <- file(tmp, "w")

        on.exit(close(tmpcon), add = TRUE)

        incomment <- FALSE

        while(length(line <- readLines(file, 1)) > 0) {
                .
                .
                . ommited in SO example
                .
                .
                .
        }
        close(tmpcon)
        close(file)
        on.exit()

        read.csv(tmp, ...)
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the add=TRUE be a parameter of the on.exit call - not the close call?  Currently for tmpcon you have add=TRUE inside of close.

Comment: I agree with you. I think that's a bug in the example so am editing it. Hopefully and R expert can review and comment.

Comment: @PreetSangha One suggestion: rewrite the line `file <- file(file, "r")`: "However, using the same name for functions and other objects will make for confusing code, and is generally best avoided." (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html). Minor stuff: `on.exit` instead of `onexeit` or `onexit`. "expressions" instead of "experssions".

Comment: @Qaswed - why don't you edit the post please to make it better? Thanks.

Comment: @PreetSangha I wanted to edit the minor stuff, but this is below the threshold SO accepts as an edit. Regarding the code: I do make suggestions for improvements, but I really don't like editing other peopels' code :)